# Regex to remove special characters from a string

Tags: python, regex, string

I'm trying to write a regex that only allows letters, numbers, single white spaces, `'-'` literal, and `'/'` literal. How do I limit my expression to only these?

If I enter `"This should be invalid because it ends with!!! these"`, it is still returned as a valid string, even though there's an exclamation at the end.
The one I have is not entirely correct:

```
[A-Z]|[a-z]|[0-9]|/|\s|-
```

Comment: Hi, I was just about to finish an answer to your Access timer question when you deleted it. :( Not nice. Care to repost it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that, by default, regular expressions do not have to match the entire string. One character is sufficient to constitute a match (and sometimes even none)! You need to surround your regex like `^(?: ... )+$` to make it work as you want:

```js
console.log([
    'This should be invalid because it ends with!!! these', //=> false
    'This is valid' //=> true
].map(/ /.test,
  /^(?:[A-Z]|[a-z]|[0-9]|\/|\s|-)+$/
))
```

However, a more compact way to write the same expression would be [`^[A-Za-z\d\s\/-]+$`](https://regex101.com/r/Jxczoy/1).

```js
console.log([
    'This should be invalid because it ends with!!! these', //=> false
    'This is valid' //=> true
].map(/ /.test,
  /^[A-Za-z\d\s\/-]+$/
))
```

Comment: Hey, this worked for me: `^(?:[A-Z]|[a-z]|[0-9]|\/|\s|-)+$` but the compact version you suggested, `^(?:[A-Za-z\d\s\/-])+$`, doesn't return the correct result. However, the first one works perfectly. :)

Comment: I'm surprised the second one didn't work for you . . . what string did you run it on and what flavor of regex are you using?

Comment: I'm using the re library in Python 3.4. Sorry, I Seem to have made an error in running it. Tried again and it ran just fine!

Comment: Oh, glad to hear! Good luck with the rest of your project :)

Comment: Thank you @gyre :)